# How can I determine whether or not a string variable is located in the middle, beginning, or end of a target variable

Tags: python

As it says in the title, I'm trying to determine the location of a string variable in a target variable. For instance:

If search string is at the very beginning of target string, then return "Beginning". For example: string_finder("Georgia Tech", "Georgia") -> "Beginning"

If search string is at the very end of target string, then return "End". For example: string_finder("Georgia Tech", "Tech") -> "End"

If search string is in target string but not at the very beginning or very end, then return "Middle. For example: string_finder("Georgia Tech", "gia") -> "Middle"

```
    def string_finder(target, search):
        if search in target[0:]:
            return "Beginning"
        elif search in target[:-1]:
            return "End"
        elif search not in target:
            return "Not found"
        else:
            return "Middle"
```

This is what I have, which obviously doesn't work. Sorry I'm still learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your approach didn't work is that `target[0:]` has the exact same contents as `target`. When you search through the former with `in`, it's identical to searching through the latter.

Similarly, `target[:-1]` is everything *except* the last character. You've got to anchor your search to the beginnings and ends.

---

So what can you do?

There are built-in string methods called `startswith` and `endswith`. Combined with the things you already tried, you can get a complete result—ignoring cases where the string *both* starts and ends with your search term.

```
def string_finder(target, search):
    if target.startswith(search):
        return "Beginning"
    elif target.endswith(search):
        return "End"
    elif search not in target:
        return "Not found"
    else:
        return "Middle"
```

Another avenue involves regular expressions, using the anchors `^` and `$`, but this approach is simpler.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this falls in line with exactly the content I am currently learning.

Answer (score 1):

The reason given by @Arya is crystal clear. You also can achieve the same by using built-in string manipulation function. For you to get familiar with slicing manipulation as well.

```py
def string_finder(target, search):
    if target.split()[0] == search:
        return 'Beginning'
    elif target.split()[-1] == search:
        return "End"
    elif search not in target.split():
        return "Not found"
    else:
        return "Middle"
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work in the general case—for beginning and end, it only works if the query is space-delimited within the target. For instance, it'll say that 'Geor' is in the middle.

Comment: Yes, I forget to mention that it assumes a space as delimiter.